# how to extract thumbail from exif using HTML5, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, exif

I am trying to implement drag'n'drop using html5. SO before uploading to server I want to display thumbnails of the dropped images. What should be the approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the thumbnail from EXIF I don't think it is possible, unless you have/write yourself an EXIF library in JavaScript to run on the browser. However if you just need the thumbnail, it is much easier:

```
   document.querySelector('#fileInputForImage').addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
              document.querySelector('#previewImage').src = e.target.result;
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      }
   }, false);
```

Note that browser support is not very good now: http://caniuse.com/filereader

Comment: I'm doing it this way right now. i.e. load and then  resize but for large images I hvae to wait till the whole image is loaded. this is the reason i was trying to get thumbnail from exif. on one of the blogs i read that we can show thumbnails of the dropped images even before the image is loaded!!